# How do I convert lots of frames to a symbol in Flash MX 2004

Tags: flash, symbols

I have 2 layers with multiple keyframes etc and I want to convert all of it to a button symbol...  It just doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

this looks more like [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/) question, but what you need to do is:

1. Copy all the frames
2. Create a new symbol( Ctrl+F8 / CMD + F8 on mac )
3. Paste all the frames
4. Maybe add a stop on the first frame of the animation, then Convert the animation to a
   Movie Clip.

Also it might be handy to use **Edit Mutliple Frames** in conjuction with **Select All**
to move the whole animation inside the symbol to get the right registration point.

I've recorded a quick screen recording and uploaded it [here](http://www.screencast.com/users/orgicus/folders/Jing/media/cedf48a0-bd59-42af-8d5a-342f25a12191).
Goodluck!

Forget about the actionscript bit in the video btw :)